# Vba Excel error using SaveAs with password

Tags: vba, excel, passwords, save-as

I wrote a simply code to save every Excel Worksheet as a new file (.xlsx) protected with password:

```
 For i = 1 To 7

   ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Copy   
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & i & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51, Password:="XXX"
   ActiveWorkbook.Close False

Next i
```

It works but the error is that the created files seem to have a sort of autorun (they auto-open if you simply click on the icons) and then the Excel popup about password shows "copy of && is protected" in adding to "&& is protected" and ask for the password twice.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: you got your quotation marks wrong here: `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & i & ".xlsx"`

Comment: Thanks but it's only a mistake here (incorrect copy and paste).. the original code is correct and partially works

Answer (score 0):

A general peace of advice, do not use ThisWorkbook, ActiveWorkbook, Active Worksheet etc. if not 100% neccessary. It more often than not causes problems. Second thing, sometimes a few more lines of code are better than less, because of debugability.

The most important points of code below: Your workbook of source is defined as `wbSource` and you initialize a variable `wbTarget`. For each worksheet in the workbook you create a new workbook by `Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Add` copy the sheet `mySheet` the iterator to it, set the password and save it. This can be done in one row, but again this is very clear and debugable.

```
Sub test()

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim wbSource As Workbook, wbTarget As Workbook
    Dim wsToCopy As Worksheet

    Set wbSource = ThisWorkbook

    For Each mySheet In wbSource.Sheets
        Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Add
        mySheet.Copy Before:=wbTarget.Sheets(1)
        wbTarget.Password = "XXX"
        wbTarget.Close True, mySheet.Name
    Next mySheet

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the clean code but the error is still there; 
it seems to be related to the conversion from .xlsm to .xlsx of the single sheet; 
the particular thing is that it also happens using the normal Excel procedure through windows without vba ("save with name" and change the extension)